# Old layer shows up when playing the timeline without video

Tags: after-effects, adobe

A while ago I made a short test animation. It was a red circle on a white background. Every time I create a new project or composition, there is always a picture of that red circle. The only time it doesn't show is when the video I am trying to edit is playing. I tried resetting my preferences and that didn't help.

Comment: I think we need more information on this. You mention that there is a "picture of that red circle". Can you attach screenshots or be more specific as to where the picture is?

Comment: @JohnBarton I don't know what happened but it's gone now. Thank you still for trying to help me!